# How to register device to receive push notifications

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to register the device into pinpoint but I received the message:

```
        public string Register()
    {

        String identityId = Credentials.GetIdentityId();
        RegisterDeviceRequest registerDevice = RegisterDevice(identityId);

        AmazonCognitoSyncClient AmazonCognitoSyncClient = new AmazonCognitoSyncClient(AwsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
        SynAmazonCognitoSyncClient(registerDevice, AmazonCognitoSyncClient);

        return null;
    }

    private static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RegisterDeviceResponse> SynAmazonCognitoSyncClient(RegisterDeviceRequest registerDevice, AmazonCognitoSyncClient AmazonCognitoSyncClient)
    {
        return AmazonCognitoSyncClient.RegisterDeviceAsync(registerDevice);
    }
```

But i received timeout on SynAmazonCognitoSyncClient

And into pinpoint dashboard, I do not have any device registered.

Some body have other forms to register device into aws pinpoint with xamarin forms ?

Comment: Refer this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-push.html

Comment: Can you post the exception message and a stacktrace? I do not see the Pinpoint client being used here. What are the AWS Xamarin SDK artifacts your app is depending on?